# how to output result outside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, prepared-statement

When i echo the ouput inside the while loop, it gives me all the result i am expecting. 
When i echo outside, however, i only get one. I know if i use an array  it will give me the result i am expecting, but don't know how. 
For some unknown reason i don't like arrays and i have been avoiding them.

```
$sql="select concat(p.firstName,' ',p.lastName) as parents 
from parent p,
parentstudent ps,
student s
where p.parent_id = ps.parent_id
and s.student_id = ps.student_id
and p.parent_id IN ('".$_SESSION['list'][1]."','".$_SESSION['list'][2]."','".$_SESSION['list'][3]."','".$_SESSION['list'][4]."' )";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo $participants = $row->parents."  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: avoiding arrays? why? they are useful

Comment: avoiding arrays in programming? are you sure?

Comment: maybe i need a better source other than http://php.net/.

Comment: Hopefully you don't have anything against functions :-) That said the answer to your question is obvious : `$row` is the value of your fesched object item while iterating on it. outside the while loop, the value is the last one the loop iterated on.

Comment: "For some unknown reason" - excuse me, what sort of reason is it? Why do you want to accumulate the output into array? If you just need to print the value, do it inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the array option is really quite simple - you first need to declare your array, before your loop starts, like this:

`$arr = array();`

We do it this way to make sure `$arr` remains in scope both within, and outside of the while loop. Then in the loop, you add items into the array like this:

`$arr[] = $row->parents;`

Combining this, we get our code:

```
$arr = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $arr[] = $row->parents;
}

print_r($arr);
```

If, after building the array, you want to revisit each element/parent value, you simply need to iterate over the array again, which you can do like this:

```
foreach($arr as $parent) {
    echo $parent . " ";
}
```

Or, you could print out the same string you print in your loop, by using `implode()` to join all the elements of the array together:

```
print implode(" ", $arr);
```

To create a prepared statement, which binds to the parents, we also need to build an array of placeholders - we can do this with `array_fill()`. We need one placeholder for each element of `$arr`, we can achieve that like this:

```
$placeholders = array_fill(0, count($arr), "?");
```

This says to build an array, from the first (0th) element, with the same number of elements as `$arr`, and fill it with question marks (the pdo placeholder - i think this is what you want to use?)

We can then build our prepared statement like this (assuming PDO):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('select .... where X IN (' . implode(",", $placeholders) . ')');
```

That will build a statement that looks like
`select .... where X IN ( ?, ?, ?, ... ? )`. 
for however many placeholders were in your array.

You can then just execute the statement, and pass it `$arr` to fill those placeholders:

`$stmt->execute($arr);`

If you are using mysqli instead, it should be similar.

Comment: Sometimes all you need is an example. Thanks! I guess i can  also assign the values as follow: $arr[0];
                                     $arr[1];
                       $arr[2];
                       $arr[3]

Comment: That is how you access specific elements directly, yes

Comment: Thanks! I want to conver my query into a prepared statment to prevent injection. My IN(values) are from a list of session. I try to store the concatenate  session into a $variable to use as $stmt->bind_param("s", $variable); but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want arrays at all (why not?) then just create a string container,

then continually concatenate strings under the loop, then finally echo:

```
$participants = ''; // initialize
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $participants .= $row->parents . "  ";
               // ^ concat
}
echo $participants;
```

The problem in your current code is that every loop, `$participants` gets overwritten:

```
echo $participants = $row->parents."  ";
             //    ^ overwrites it every iteration
```